# How is the あげたい working here?

Tags: grammar, nuances, verbs, perspective

On a TV show, an idol was given this task to think of:

> 心が晴れやかになる一言
>   'A word (or phrase) to lift someone's mood'　　(My loose translation)

The idol responded:

> アナタの心の雨を[止]{や}ませてあげたいな
>   'Let me try and get rid of that cloud hanging over you'.　　(Very loose translation, I know)

So, more literally translated, I guess it would be:

> 'Let me stop the rain in your heart'.

I would like to know how `あげたい` works here. Is it working like:

> I'd like to give you my action of stopping the rain in your heart

Or is it working differently?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I help you?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/can-i-help-you)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`〜てあげる` is the form of "doing X for someone".  The quote is just the combination of that and the `〜たい` form (want to do).  So it is "I want to do X for you".  Of course, remember that `〜てあげる` should not be used for 目上の人, and even when used properly might sound patronizing in the wrong context.