# Why is こと used in 「私に何かできること」？

Tags: grammar, word-usage, particle-こと

How does it turn this into a noun clause? All I get from it is “I can do something” but I don’t see where こと fits in.[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

私に何かできること translates to a noun phrase "something I can do". This こと is not a particle but a simple noun meaning "thing". And 私に何かできる is a **relative clause** that modifies こと. This seems to be the first time you asked about relative clauses on this site, but real Japanese sentences are full of relative clauses, and you probably have seen this construction before.

Let's start from this sentence:

> 私には医療通訳ができる。
>   I can do medical translation.

In case you're not sure what this に is doing, see: [Why say "〜、皆には出来る。" instead of " 〜、皆は出来る。" in this context?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36481/5010)

Next, with [the basic grammar of relative clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14550/5010) in mind, you can form the following noun phrase from the first sentence:

> 私にできること
>   the thing I can do

So I changed 医療通訳 to こと, and pulled it out to the end of the sentence. I also changed には to に.

何か [is an *adverb*](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BD%95%E3%81%8B) rather than a noun here. It adds the meaning of "some", "something", "somehow", etc. (e.g., 何か本を読もう = "I'll read some book", 何か単語を言ってください = "Say some (random) word.")

> 私に何かできること
>   something I can do

Finally, I feel this is **not** something this (seemingly Japanese) lady is *saying* to the other people. Saying "Something I can do!" suddenly to people around you makes no sense. So it's either a catchphrase of this ad or what she is *thinking*, i.e., "(So this is) something I can do!". If you're interested in how to say "Can I help you" in Japanese, see: [Can I help you?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1465/5010)

Comment: 英訳についてですが、「私にできること」  はそのままでは基本的には“something I can do” と訳されます。なので、”The thing I can do“と訳したい場合は「（これが）私にできること」という風にかっこ書きを添える必要があります。「私に何かできること」はその逆で、そのままでは不完全な為、“Something I can do“と訳したい場合は”(Is there) something I can do”や“(Whether there is) something I can do”、 “(There must be) something I can do…”などと言った感じで、今度は英訳のほうにかっこ書きを添えなければなりません。あと、文脈も文脈ですし、この場合は”Something I can help with”が最も適確な英訳になるかと思います。

Comment: @VVayfarer この語中の「何か」の働きは副詞的であり、それ自体が疑問文やembedded questionを構成するわけではないと思います。「何か」を付けると "is there" や "whether" みたいな意味が突然増えるかのように解説するのは誤解を招くと思います。「飲むもの」を "beverage" とするか "something to drink" とすべきか "(the) thing that I drink" とすべきかは「状況による」としか言いようがありませんが、このレベルの質問者に対して「こと」の文法的働きを逐語訳で解説するという文脈であれば、最も無難なのは3番目ではないかな、と。

Comment: しかし、かっこ書きを添えることで「こういう文脈の場合はこの翻訳が妥当で、文脈が違えば翻訳もまた変わる」的な意味合いを含めることができるので、寧ろ誤解を避けるのに便利な筈です。特にこの場合、「私にできること」を”The thing I can do”とするのも、「私に何かできること」を”something I can do”とするのも英訳としてはかなり異例なので、「このケース以外では通用しない可能性が高い」ということを何らかの方法で表現するべきではないでしょうか。今のままでは、これを読んだ人が翻訳をそのまま真に受けてしまって、「何か、**私にできること**はありますか？」を”Something, is there **the thing I can do**?”と英訳したり、”This is **something I can do**”を「これは**私に何かできること**だ」と和訳したりなど、かなり混乱してしまう恐れもあります。

Comment: @VVayfarer まさに質問者がそれに近い間違いをしていることに気づいたので、この「何か」が「something/somehow 的な意味を加える副詞であって、somethingそのものではない」ということを当初から明白に強調して説明したつもりです（例文は後から加えましたが）。

Answer (score 1):

It's short for「私に何かできることはありますか？」or "Is there something I could help with?"

A similar and much more common abbreviated phrase is「私に何か用」, from「私に何か用ですか」or「私に何か用があるんですか？」. I believe the phrase in the example was created as an allusion (for lack of a better term) to this one, and by this I mean that it was likely artificially made to resemble「私に何か用」to make it 'sound better'.

And to be more clear,「私に何かできること」in itself would never be used in isolation. In other words, as is often the case in advertisements, what "sounds good" (from the perspective of the people who came up with the concept) was prioritized in this case over correct language.

Comment: 英語だと "Anything I can help?" と聞くのはアリなのかもしれませんが、日本語で「私に何かできること」が「私に何かできることはありますか」の短縮形として解釈されることは、ほぼ絶対にないと思うのですが。

Comment: @naruto 流石にそれは弁えています。だからこそ「Allusion」かと。「私になにか用」的な感じで「私になにかできることがありますか」が変換された結果だと推測しました。Narutoさんも回答で述べた通り、広告だし、Catchphraseで間違いないとは思いますが

Comment: 「これは日本語できない人が妄想で作った間違った日本語の広告だ」という解釈もアリかもしれませんが、それならこの文は間違っているともっと明確に述べた方がいいと思います。

Comment: @naruto いやーしかし、作った側もそれを承知の上でやったのではないでしょうか。よくはわかりませんが、広告というのは得てしてそういうものだという印象があります。言葉や文法がめちゃくちゃでも「それっぽく聞こえればいい」といった感じで。その意図までは読めませんが、形が「私に何か用」に激似している為、敢えてそれに似せようとした結果ではないかと推測したまでです。ただ、「そのままでは不完全」だと明言すべきだったという指摘に関しては、確かにそうかもしれませんね