# に particle used with ある

Tags: particle-に

> できることが僕にある

This sounds like "the things I can do is in me", which doesn't makes sense. Translation tells me it actually means "I can do something". Why is に used rather than が? What rule does this に follow? I haven't seen this kind of に anywhere so far (with my limited japanese). Also what is the difference in using に and が here?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/68328/why-is-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8-used-in-%E7%A7%81%E3%81%AB%E4%BD%95%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8
This is related, the に or には makes the sentence mean "There are things I can do", but I wouldn't know the difference between just 僕は and 僕に or 僕には

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24955/use-of-%e3%81%ab-in-%e7%a7%81%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af%e6%9c%ac%e7%89%a9%e3%81%ae%e8%8b%a5%e6%ae%bf%e6%a7%98%e3%81%8c%e3%82%8f%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%99 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13323/the-%e3%81%ab-particle-and-potential-form/13330#13330 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/%e3%81%8c-and-%e3%81%ab-interchangeability-and-difference-in-meaning

Comment: Does this answer your question? [が and に interchangeability and difference in meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/%e3%81%8c-and-%e3%81%ab-interchangeability-and-difference-in-meaning)

Answer (score 1):

> できることが僕にある
>
> This sounds like "the things I can do is in me", which doesn't makes sense.

This is the second time I've seen you post a question where you insist that Japanese に must correspond exactly to English "in", then claim confusion. The origin of the confusion is in your insistence on translating に only into "in".

> Translation tells me it actually means "I can do something".

You can translate it as "There are things which I can do" and here the "there are" corresponds to にある in the Japanese. You could actually think of it as "In me there are things I can do" if it helps you to understand, but of course the English is far from natural.