Usage of potential + に?
So there is a love triangle between two girls and one dude.
The girls are fighting for the same dude and the girls reveals the guy proposed to her and says this
彼とあたしいずれ家族になるの。お前に家族なんて作れない！
I get the girl says "Him and I are going to be a family one day" but I don't see what is the second sentence trying to say? "You cannot give him a family?" Why is に used here?

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13323/the-%e3%81%ab-particle-and-potential-form/

I don't think this is particular to the potential form. に doesn't only indicate "targets" of actions, but also e.g. beneficiaries.

This question is similar to: Use of に in 「私には本物の若殿様がわかります」. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4440/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68328/5010

Does this mean the sentence would also work with は?

@LionGate yes it would. This　に　isn’t paired with the verb 作れる, but you should see it as お前に(とって)家族なんて作れない
